# Laravel Voyager doesn't display uploaded images after uploaded to server

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, voyager

#### Problem description

I have a Laravel project with Voyager, and it works fine on localhost, but after uploaded images not displaying

#### What I tried

`php artisan storage:link`

in `.env` I tried `APP_URL=http://localhost` / `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000` / `APP_URL=<server-ip>`, but nothing works.

#### Facts

- Voyager version is `1.3`
- The domain of the project is heading to `/public` directory I didn't change anything about `public/index.php` nor `.htaccess`.

Comment: Anything in the log? Is the filesystem writable to the php process user? Can another standalone php file write to where the images need to be written?

Comment: Check whether the `storage` symbolic link present in the public directory, if yes delete it and with in voyager dashboard there will be a message to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution
in `.env` file change `APP_URL` to `<server-ip>/public`
Now all images work fine
hope someone else will find this usefull.